# Symfony 3. Cookie auto deletes immediately after create

Tags: symfony, cookies

I create cookie in EventSubscriber:

```
function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $cookie_data = 'test';
        $cookie = new Cookie('test_cookie', $cookie_data, strtotime('now +1 year'));

        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
        $response->send();
}
```

then I watch to Application tab in Chrome and press F5.
this cookie appears for 0.5 sec and automatically remove

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps somebody.

I found problem: nginx send missed static files like .jpg to application.

When i fix nginx vhost file - cookies starts to set correctly.